# À son côté / à côté de / au côté de

Tags: expressions, prépositions

> En s’apercevant que je ne suis plus **à son côté**, A. se tourne.

*À côté de A.*, *au côté de A.* et *aux côtés de A*. ont une signification un peu différente.

*B. est à côté de A.* veut dire *B. se trouve à gauche ou à droite de A*.

*B. est au côté de A*. veut dire *B. est plus près de A., à sa gauche ou à sa droit*e.

*B. est aux côtés de A.* a un sens figuré (B. soutient A.)

Mais lorsque l'on écrit *à son côté*, comment est-il possible de savoir s'il s'agit de ***à** côté de A.* ou ***au** côté de A.* ?

Answer (score 1):

La phrase ne peut signifier que: *En s'apercevant que je ne suis plus à côté de lui, A. se tourne.*

*Au côté de* et *à son côté* ont pour moi le même sens. Ils ne sont pas très courants et peuvent signifier *à côté de* au sens propre comme au sens figuré (dans ce dernier cas, similaires à *aux côtés de*, *à ses côtés*).

Je ne perçois pas le sens *plus près de, sur le côté* attribué à *au côté de* dans la question.

Comment: _Je ne perçois pas le sens plus près de..._ Je voulais dire que dans _au côté de_ B. se rapproche davantage de A. par rapport à _à côté de_. // _La phrase ne peut signifier que..._ Je ne comprends pas cette phrase.  Donc, _à son côté_ veut dire _au côté_ et non _à côté_ ?

Comment: *Ne peut signifier que xxx* est équivalent à *ne peut pas signifier autre chose que xxx*.

Comment: *Au côté* peut c'est vrai être utilisé quand le côté fait partie de l'objet (ou la personne). *Il a deux trous rouges au côté droit*. [Le dormeur du val](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Dormeur_du_val) Dans ce cas, *à côté* est exclu.

Comment: À propos du 1er commentaire, oui, je le sais, mais je n'ai pas compris le sens de toute la 1ère phrase et de la 2ème. À mon avis, elle se contredisent. La 1ère dit : _à son côté_ = _à côté de lui_ alors que la 2ème _à son côté_ = _au côté de_. Donc, ma question est _à son côté_ = _à côté de lui_ ou _au côté de lui_ ?

Comment: Les phrases ne se contredisent pas. Le première donne le sens de l'expression *à son côté* dans la phrase de la question. La deuxième concerne le cas général et dit que *à son côté* est moins courant que *à côté de* et *aux côtés de* et peut signifier l'un comme l'autre suivant le contexte. D'autre part *au côté de* (au singulier) est lui aussi moins courant et peut avoir les mêmes sens, là aussi suivant le contexte.